# Running a php script in crontab

Tags: php, cron

I'm trying to run a php script every day at 01:00 UTC. I have the line
`00 01 * * * /usr/bin/php -f /var/www/html/test.php`
in my crontab, but for some reason it's not running my script. I know the script itself works because I've tested it. It just won't run in the crontab. I've also tried using

```
00 01 * * * php /var/www/html/test.php
```

but that didn't work either. I've added `#!/usr/bin/php` to the very beginning of the php script I am trying to run. I've also tried a -q instead of -f. Nothing has worked, and I'm not sure what I can do to fix this. Is there some other method I should try if this still doesn't work?

Comment: Which owner and group does test.php belong to? and have you tried running it from the command line?

Comment: Also, are you specifying the correct path to PHP?

Comment: It's a file created by root user. I also tried changing the privileges using chmod +x test.php  
On the command line I ran the command "php /var/www/html/test.php" and the script did exactly what I wanted it to do.

Comment: It should be the correct path to PHP. When I do "whereis php" I get php: /usr/bin/php /etc/php.ini /etc/php.d /usr/include/php /usr/share/man/man1/php.1.gz

Comment: Have you tried using lynx to launch the script? (It looks like it is accessible via URL). Ex: 
00 01 * * * lynx -dump http://www.mywebsite.com/test.php

Comment: @fcr91, It should work based on what you've mentioned. One more thought is to chmod the file to 755 if not already.

Comment: @l'L'l 750 should be sufficient. The public doesn't need access to his crons.

Comment: I'm talking about the php - and 644 should be sufficient — but it really all depends on what the `php` does.

Comment: When you say you've tested this script, how exactly did you test it? Did you enter `/usr/bin/php -f /var/www/html/test.php` at the command line, or did you use a browser to visit `/test.php` in your website? If the former is true, then you probably have something wrong with your cron configuration. If the latter is true, you should bear in mind that the script will be running in a different environment when called from the command line. For example, `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` will most likely be somewhere else altogether.

Comment: @I'L'I Just did chmod to 755 and it still didn't work

Comment: @squeamishossifrage I did the former in the command line to test the script

Comment: Have you tried dumping the output to a file to see if everything is going well? Ex: 00 01 * * * /usr/bin/php -f /var/www/html/test.php > /tmp/cron.log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was writing a ksh script that exported more paths and then ran the php script. This worked.

`export ORACLE_HOME=/opt/oracle/product/11.2.0/client
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/oracle/product/11.2.0/client/lib/
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/oracle/product/11.2.0/client/bin
php /var/www/html/test.php`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your paths are correct. Try this syntax:

```
cd /var/www/html; php -q -c ./ test.php
```

The `-q` flag suppresses any header() from being written to standard out. This forces your script to be executed with the php-cgi binary instead of the command-line version.

The `-c` flag prevents the OS from changing directories since you do that with `cd`.

Comment: is this for the crontab?

Comment: yessir. @fcr91 you can use a semicolon to execute two commands at once.

Answer (score 0):

having a local 
 web server running, you may call

```
http://localhost/test.php
```

from your crontab